# How can I use an array in a procedure

Tags: arrays, delphi, procedure

This is the code I use if I'm working with one array. I want to adjust this code so that it can work with any array by using a procedure:

```
Var
  tf: TextFile;
  sWord: String;
  i: Integer;
  arrDurban: array of string;
begin
  if Location='Durban' then
  begin
    i := 0;
    SetLength(arrDurban, 1);
    AssignFile(tf, '');
    Reset(tf);
    while not eof(tf) do
    begin
      Readln(tf, sWord);
      arrDurban[i] := sWord;
      Inc(i);
      SetLength(arrDurban, i + 1);
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Or you can use `IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllLines` and get a much faster version. If you don't want that, I still wonder why you want a procedure and not an array-returning function.

Comment: I thought a procedure would be the best option but I wasn't to sure on that

Comment: `function ReadFile(const ALocation: string): TArray<string>`

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand how must I adjust my code to work with the function?

Comment: @PreshenGovender Why is this code allocating `arrDurban` to always contain 1 more string than is actually read from the file? In any case, another alternative to using a dynamic array is to use `TStringList` instead, with its `LoadFromFile()` method

Comment: @MartynA clearly `arrDurban` is declared as an `array of string` or maybe a `TArray<string>`, otherwise the code shown would not compile.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Well, it could also be an array of records with an implicit conversion operator from `string`. (But of course it isn't.)

Comment: Sorry about that it was set as array of string.